# How to create sourceset in custom plugin

Tags: gradle

I'm writing custom plugin which should create number of sourcesets depends on plugin extension. 
How can I do it in apply method?

Here's my code snippets (both don't work), labels - list from extension:

1.

```
    project.sourceSets {
        labels.each { info ->
            "${info.lower}Src" {
                java.srcDirs = ['src'] + info.srcPostfix.collect { postfix -> "src_custom/${postfix}" }
            }
        }
        main { java.srcDirs = ['src'] + labels.collect { info -> "src_custom/${info.lower}" } }
        test { java.srcDirs = ['test'] + labels.collect { info -> "test_custom/${info.lower}" } }
    }
```

2.

```
    labels.each { info ->
        SourceSet modelSrc = project.sourceSets.create("${info.lower}Src")
        modelSrc.getJava().setSrcDirs(['src'] + info.srcPostfix.collect { postfix -> "src_custom/${postfix}" })
    }
    SourceSetContainer sourceSets = project.convention.getPlugin(JavaPluginConvention).sourceSets
    SourceSet mainSourceSet = sourceSets.getByName(MAIN_SOURCE_SET_NAME)
    mainSourceSet.getJava().setSrcDirs(['src'] + labels.collect { info -> "src_custom/${info.lower}" })
    SourceSet testSourceSet = sourceSets.getByName(TEST_SOURCE_SET_NAME)
    testSourceSet.getJava().setSrcDirs(['test'] + labels.collect { info -> "test_custom/${info.lower}" })
```

Comment: Don't work? What does it mean exactly?

Comment: @Opal thanks for comment. If I try to run './gradlew build' on project which applies my plugin, it can't find "${label.lower}SrcCompile" tasks. And in latest IntellijIdea "src_custom/${label.lower}" folders are not marked as source folders.

Comment: the task you're writing about will not be created. Added sources will be compiled using standard tasks. Could You please provide SSCCE? A good example illustrating what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Opal In build.gradle of my java project I can "apply plugin: java" and then use 1st variant: "sourceSets {...}". In this case I have correct "${label}Src" sourceSet and "#{label}SrcCompile" task for each label (labels - list of strings). Now I want to move this code to custom plugin and use only "apply plugin: my-custom-plugin" in my project's build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but here's what I ran into. I needed to create a plugin that would create a sourceSet. What I had before was this in my `build.gradle`

```
sourceSets {
    myNewSet {
        groovy.srcDir file("${project.myNewSet_src}")
        resources.srcDir file("${project.myNewSet_resources}")
    }
}
```

So when I created my plugin, in the `apply` method, I had this:

```
project.getSourceSets().create("myNewSet", {
    groovy.srcDir new File("${project.getProjectDir()}/${project.myNewSet_src}")
    resources.srcDir new File("${project.getProjectDir()}/${project.myNewSet_resources}")
});
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example what does it look like in Kotlin Gradle DSL, configuring Spring Boot's BootRun task project-wide in multiproject build:

```kotlin
tasks {
    withType<BootRun> {
        val createGitRevisionReport: GitRevisionReportTask by this@tasks
        dependsOn(createGitRevisionReport)
        val sourceSets = project.convention.getPlugin(JavaPluginConvention::class.java).sourceSets
        val additionalSourceSet = sourceSets.create("bootRunAdditionalSourceSet") {
            resources.srcDir(createGitRevisionReport.gitRevisionReportDir)
        }
        sourceResources(additionalSourceSet)
    }
}
```